# Overriding FindByEmail to find by tenant too

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a multi-tenant application which tenant share the same database thus meaning the user store is shared.

Therefore, I've created my own `UserStore` like so:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUserStore(IdentityDbContext dbContext)
    : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        user.TenantId = TenantId;
        return base.CreateAsync(user, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return base.FindByEmailAsync(normalizedEmail, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to add to the `FindByEmailAsync` call to also grab the user with the corresponding email and tenant.

How should I tackle this? I'm using .NET Core 2.2 and looking at this guide: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy?fbclid=IwAR3F2NmmCoSHfxvIPwpQ0l-gTthFfVICaTdU2etcHyN--UEm-Nd6OP0LnLE it looks like `GetUserAggregateAsync` has been stripped out of 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tenant filter, you could try [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<SystemUser,IdentityRole<int>,int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<SystemUser>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<int>(b, "TenantId") == TenantId);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may need to implement your own `GetUserAggregateAsync` by referring [GetUserAggregateAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/a24b776676f12cf7f0e13944783cf8e379b3ef70/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs#L891)

Comment: Great...the Global Query Filters sample saved me many hours. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Just a query here. Is there a way to set TenantId in Startup.cs file? I want to store the TenantId in appsettings.json file.